# Determining the probability of an observation provided distributions using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have two sets of about 15000 points describing various observations of a seemingly random variable according to two possible states, S1 or S2. These two sets are store in numpy arrays.
Let's assume the distrubutions are not "classical" and are overlapping.

Now I have a new observation, and I would like to know if it is more likely to be related to state S1 or S2.

I know how to use `numpy.quantile` to get any quantile value for my two distributions but now I would like to use it in a reverse manner so that I can get directly the related quantile for each distributions.

I see how I could do this by brute force and dichotomie search but I feel there must be a more efficient, "pythonic" way.

Is there a numpy function to do so ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, silly question, obvious answer.

There obviously is something available in python, but not in numpy, in scipy.

```
from scipy import stats

print(stats.percentileofscore(array_distribution_S1,observation))
print(stats.percentileofscore(array_distribution_S2,observation))
```

This enables to select which distribution is the most probable.